# Sum list of Option[Int] Scala using fold

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold

I was trying to sum all elements in a list, they are of type Option[Int], if any of them are None, the whole result is None, if all are Some(value), I want the sum of all of them:

```
val ls = List(Some(2), Some(5), Some(4), Some(1))

ls.fold(None)((rs,x) => for(n <- x; m <- rs) yield {n+m})
```

but I always get None, no matter what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this also:

```
val ls = List(Some(2), Some(5), Some(4), Some(1))
val sum = ls.foldLeft(Option(0))((so, io) => so.flatMap(s => io.map(s + _)))
```

If any single value in the list is `None`, then `sum` is reported as `None`; otherwise - if all values are defined - you get a `Some` containing the sum of elements. If the list is empty, then you'd get `Some(0)` as the result.

Comment: Hey, I like it very much, plus one. I will try it a little and see if I can understand it as well, did you say my version with fold right?

Comment: @DamianLattenero Yes. The two answers are equivalent.

Comment: Yeah I can see, I like the variant with flatmap and map, interesting

Answer (score 3):

I realize what was my error, it was the base case in fold:

```
val ls = List(Some(2), Some(5), Some(4), Some(1))

ls.fold(Some(0))((rs,x) => for(n <- x; m <- rs) yield {n+m})
```

Instead of None as case Base, I put 0, but with the context of Option.

Answer (score 1):

First use forall to check whether all values are defined or not,and then apply fold to get sum if defined else None.

```
scala> val ls = List(Some(2), Some(5), Some(4), Some(1))
ls: List[Some[Int]] = List(Some(2), Some(5), Some(4), Some(1))

scala> if(ls.forall(_.isDefined)) Some(ls.flatten.foldLeft(0){_ + _ }) else None
res22: Option[Int] = Some(12)

scala> val ls = List(Some(2), None,Some(5), Some(4), Some(1),None)
ls: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(2), None, Some(5), Some(4), Some(1), None)

scala> if(ls.forall(_.isDefined)) Some(ls.flatten.foldLeft(0){_ + _ }) else None
res23: Option[Int] = None

scala>
```

Comment: No no, I don't want an Int result, I want an Option[Int] result, check my answer or the answer with fold left and you will understand better my question

Comment: So you want ans either in  Some(sum) if defined else None ?

Comment: something like that, if only one is None, all is None, if all are some, sone(result)

Comment: Done. Have  a look at it!

Comment: That's ok now, nice! thanks for show another alternative! Plus one

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and return just an `Int` as well. This also avoids iterating over the `List` multiple times.

```
val foo = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3))

foo.foldLeft(0)((acc, optNum) => acc + optNum.getOrElse(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
ls.foldLeft (0) (_ + _.getOrElse (0))
```

or even

```
(0 /: ls) (_ + _.getOrElse (0))
```